# Python pandas: calculate the statistical range for all the columns.

Tags: pandas

Using python pandas, i have a dataframe with some columns of int type. i need to calculate the statistical range for all the columns. I'm able to calculate the min and max for each column but could not figure how to calculate range for all the columns

Comment: See [ask]. You should probably show a [mcve] and make it clear what you are trying to do and what results you get.

Answer (score 2):

You may check `describe`

```
df.describe(include='int64')
Out[10]: 
            cost      value
count   2.000000   2.000000
mean   20.500000  25.000000
std     7.778175   7.071068
min    15.000000  20.000000
25%    17.750000  22.500000
50%    20.500000  25.000000
75%    23.250000  27.500000
max    26.000000  30.000000
```